# SQL Server : where with cast(value as varbinary) vs cast(value as varbinary(300))

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Are there any theoretical performance differences between these queries in the scenarios below.

Scenarios are:

- `MyTable has Value nvarchar(300)`
- `MyTable has Value nvarchar(max)`

**Q1:**

```
declare @p nvarchar(3);
set @p = 'Foo';
select foo from MyTable where cast(value as varbinary) = cast(@p as varbinary);
```

**Q2:**

```
declare @p nvarchar(3);
set @p = 'Foo';

/****
x below should be:
- 300 when table allows value to me nvarchar(300)
- `max` when table allows value to be `nvarchar(max)`
****/

select foo from MyTable where cast(value as varbinary(x)) = cast(@p as varbinary(x));
```

Comment: `cast(value as varbinary)` will truncate the value to 30 bytes. You should avoid any functions on columns including `casts` if you care about performance as it almost always makes the expression unsargable. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: So then I need to specify the max length of the nvarchar column. I need to do a exact match and don't want to go the collate path.

Comment: If the column is indexed `where value = @p AND cast(value as varbinary(x)) = cast(@p as varbinary(x));` would probably be better as at least that can use the index then discard those that aren't an exact binary match.

Comment: The column is indexed, yes, but will it not evaluate the second part anyway?

Comment: It'll evaluate it, but it won't use any index, which is why the `value = @p` is first in the WHERE clause (because that will use an index). A type conversion like this will not use an index.